# Calling a function when I click on a link

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee

So in my JSF page I have a outputText that its content is generate by the managed bean.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.show(id)}" />
```

Then here is the method `show()` inside managed bean `bean`.

```
public String show(Long fromUserId){
     User from = myEJB.findUserById(fromUserId);  
     String content = "";
     //This method contains complex business logics, below are just an illustration
     if(...){
         content += ... ;  //generate some content here
         content += "<a href=\"Profile.jsf?userId=" + fromUserId + "\">";
         content += from.getFname() + " " + from.getLname() + "</a>
     }else if(...){
         //code that required to access database
         content += ...;
     }else if(...){
         content += ...;
     }
     ...
     return content;
}
```

So on my page, I have some content and a link I will link to my profile page. What I want is that when I click on the link, **I want to invoke a method that will run some of my business logic before redirect me to the Profile.jsf page**. So I guess I need to write some javascript that when i click the link, it will invoke a method, which will return a String that redirect me to Profile.jsf. I try this, but does not work

```
public String show(Long fromUserId){
     ...
     content += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"goToProfile(1)\">";
     content += from.getFname() + " " + from.getLname() + "</a>
     return content;
}

public String gotoProfile(Long id){
     //Some business logic
     return "Profile.jsf?faces-redirect=true&amp;userId=" + id;
}
```

Help please

**EDIT**

@BalusC: I try what you suggest, but due to the way I design, it does not work. Here is why: I have 3 `View Scoped Managed Bean` pages [CentralFeed.jsf, Profile.jsf, TextBook.jsf] that using the same header, so I create a template page for the header like below.

`template-header.xhtml`

```
<h:form style="display: inline;">
    <p:menuButton value="#{SessionBean.option}" >                                        
        <p:menuitem value="My Profile" ajax="false" action="#{SessionBean.goToProfile}" />
        <p:menuitem value="Stanford University" ajax="false" action="#{SessionBean.goToCentral}" />
        <p:menuitem value="Universal Trade" ajax="false" action="#{SessionBean.goToTrade}" />
   </p:menuButton>
</h:form> 
<ui:insert name="body"/>
```

then my three jsf pages will use `ui:composition` and `ui:define` to include the template header. So the header of my template page have a [Primefaces menu button](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubutton.jsf) This menu button bind to a `Session Scoped Managed Bean`. When you click on an item of this menu button, you will be redirect to one of the three jsf page. But I also want the menu button to reflect correctly which page I am look at. So here is my attempt

SessionBean.java  ---> Session Scoped Managed Bean

```
public static final String MY_PROFILE = "My Profile";
public static final String CENTRAL_FEED = "Stanford University";
public static final String TRADE = "Universal Trade";
private String option = null;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){        
    me = scholarEJB.findUserByUserName(getLoginUserName());                
    if(me != null){        
    HttpServletRequest request =
            (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String path = request.getServletPath();
    if(path.contains("Profile")){
        option = MY_PROFILE;
    }else if(path.contains("CentralFeed")){
        option = CENTRAL_FEED;
    }else if(path.contains("TextBook")){
        option = TRADE;
    }else{
        option = " ";
    }
} 
public String goToProfile(){
    option = MY_PROFILE;
    return "Profile.jsf?faces-redirect=true&amp;userId="+me.getId();
}
public String goToCentral(){
    option = CENTRAL_FEED;
    return "CentralFeed.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String goToTrade(){
    option = TRADE;
    return "TextBook.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

That work if I navigate using the menu button, but from any of the 3 page, I can also navigate to the others, and I still want the menu button to reflect correctly which page I am looking at. So let take a look at CentralFeed.jsf. So for a link to Profile.jsf I would do this

```
<p:commandLink value="Profile"
        action="#{CentralFeed.goToProfile(CentralFeed.me.id)}" ajax="false"/>
```

So in CentralFeed.java, I have:

```
public String goToProfile(Long userId){
    sessionBean.setOption(SessionBean.MY_PROFILE);  //sessionBean: Session Scoped Bean reference
    return "Profile.jsf?faces-redirect=true&amp;userId=" + userId;
}
```

When I click the link, I got redirect to Profile.jsf, and the value of the menu button is `MY_PROFILE`. That work, I only have problem when I have to do lot of business logic to figure out what should be the output. That is what I try to do in my original code above. Depend on certain condition, I will generate the HTML. But now the link that I generate by `<a href="...">`, will only take me straight to `Profile.jsf`, but dont allow me to change the value of the menu button. Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the desired job in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` in a managed bean which is associated with `Profile.jsf` by EL. You can use `@ManagedProperty` to let JSF set request parameters in the managed bean.

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.userId}")
private Long userId;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // Do business stuff based on userId.
}
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, I must say that I agree with Thorbjørn. I know that you're already using JSF 2.0 / Facelets. Just create a Facelets include template or composite component for that. Plain vanilla HTML does not really belong in the Model, but in the View.

Comment: I just update my post, would you please take a look at the EDIT part of my post

Comment: I think some concrete code would help a bit to understand the functional requirement...

Comment: If something does not make sense to you, please let me know. Your solution only work, if I refresh the page again. Is there another way to do this? Or do you suggest me to bring those dynamically generated HTML code out to the JSF page, and rendered them on/off with the same condition as I have for the if/else statement in my original code.

Comment: Sorry, the relationship between the requirement, the code and the issue is not immediately obvious, I don't have plenty of time right now to dig in the provided information and decipher it (I've got a job done as well ;) ). Later tonight maybe.

Comment: My sincere apology. I will try to revised my post to make things a bit more sense. Thank you very much

Comment: Don't take it personally :) It might for instance be a PrimeFaces bug which I am not aware of. I would need to create and run some snippet locally to be able to experience and debug the whole issue by myself. And that simply costs some time which I usually won't spend during work hours.

Comment: @BalusC, if you got the job done, you have plenty of time ;-)

Comment: @Thor: Haha. Well, I have the main advantage that I don't need to travel (I just work from a home office). I spend that time on SO. And also in the meanwhile, when something needs to be pulled, built, deployed, restarted, pushed, etc, I do a quick F5 on SO to handle comments and/or pick one question or two from the top list.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you man. You always been very helpful. I just revised my post. I hope that it is a bit more readable. Thank you again

Comment: I've read it once again and I think I get it. But do you really need to invoke business logic *before* the page is opened? Why not instead do it in constructor/postconstruct of some request/view scoped bean which is associated with the page in question, e.g. `ProfileBean`, `CentralBean` and `TradeBean`? Then you can just use `<h:outputLink>` or `<h:link>` and the initial answer still remains. You only need to change the session scoped bean behind the menubutton value to be a request scoped one instead so that the right value can be determined during its (post)construction.

Comment: Actually, what you said kind of give me a kick start. If I change the scoped of the bean associate with the menubutton to view scoped, then theoretically mine code should work, because right now, I look at the URL and determine what should be the value of menubutton, but since I have it session scoped, I only do it once. I need to have it view scoped, so that I will check the url every time I change to a new page. Uhmmm Why did I not think of that earlier. Let me give it a quick try

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSF 2.0 you should look into doing these kind of HTML generation snippets as *composite components*.  h:outputText is intended to generate human viewable text and the attribute to disable escaping is brittle in my experience.

Comment: I would like to vote this, but this does after all not answer the concrete question :) It's more a comment.

Comment: I do feel that there are flaws in my design. I am still learning :) I have revised my code, with better structure and also explain why I generate the HTML inside my managed bean. Do you think there is a better design for me?

Comment: @Harry, please read up on _composite components_, and then listen to BalusC.

Comment: Take me couple days to finally understand the need to create composite components. I am now rewriting my code to use composite components. It does give me more control over my component, and like @BalusC said, plain HTML belong to the view not the Model. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to prevent the browser from loading the HREF attribute and execute a JS code instead. You can do that like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="runScript()">
```

then just define the runScript() function to do whatever you want it to do (the business logic) and at the end load the new page:

```
function runScript(Long id)
{
    // business logic
    // ...

    location.href = 'Profile.jsf?faces-redirect=true&amp;userId=' + id;
}
```